# Upload pdf to amazon in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

I have rails app which works with pdf files using PDFKit. 
I have no problems with

```
kit = PDFKit.new(data)

kit.to_file("some.pdf")
```

What I need as result - save my pdf to Amazon S3. How is it possible to save it directly to the S3 or upload it from tmp/ folder (as I'm going to deploy it on Heroku)

Comment: I'd recommend you to read about ActiveStorage. (you can user Carrierwave or Paperclip too if you use older Rails versions or you just prefer them).

Comment: I suppose the best way is to use active storage. I was trying to make it work for almost whole day.... Can you give me a hint with code how to make it work? @arieljuod

Comment: I'm not sure where are you stuck, check the official docs https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html. You can find how to configure the s3 service, you set a `has_one_attached :pdf_file` on the model and then you can do something like `your_object.pdf_file.attach(pdf_file_object)`.

Comment: Well, I have added `has_one_attached :pdf_file` to my Page model and try to call `<% Page.pdf_file.attach(io: File.open('tmp/'), filename: 'some.pdf') %>`. As the result I get `undefined method 'pdf_file' for Page(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime):Class` @arieljuod

Comment: Could you write simple code example for model, controller and view please? @arieljuod

Comment: `pdf_file` will be a method of an instance of that class, not a method of the class. If you have a Page model, then you should have a page object and then you can do `@page.pdf_file.attach(io: File.open("/the/full/path/to/the_file.pdf", filename: 'the_file.pdf')`, i'm not sure what you would need as an example of a view or a controller since the important logic is the attach method, the rest has nothing to do, or you could at least show you current code to propose fixes for it.

Comment: Well, after some tries looks like I have some changes for better But still can't make it work. Here is my model: `class Page < ApplicationRecord  has_one_attached :pdf_file end`. In my view file I do `<% upload = Page.new %>` and `<% upload.pdf_file.attach(io: File.open('./test.html'), filename: 'test.html') %>`. Finaly my application starts without any errors. But when I check S3 account I do not see file there. In my terminal I see `S3 Storage (990.4ms) Uploaded file to key: CRt4d6buVvV1GeXBAj9jS4e3 (checksum: LzZmbetveBcxK3j4fYMVrA==)` @arieljuod

Comment: I guess you don't actually want to associate the pdf file to an object and that's why it's not really working. If you just want to save files directly to S3 use the official sdk https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/index.html

Comment: I was confused initially when doing these tasks. Just use ActiveStorage and official AWS gems and follow the gem docs. It will work like a charm.